# .net localization messages in xml configuration file instead of resources

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, resources

I am wandering if I use xml configuration files(like castle.windsors component xmls) to store my localization strings and messages instead of resources file for the sake of flexibility. I may need to change messages frequently and getting frequent builds freaks me out. As the size of document I can say that I will have a couple of thousands strings stored in multiple xml files according to the languages. Is it a good practice to do this that way?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this Globalisation system provided by MVP RIck Strahl should suit your needs nicely and provide a lovely interface at the same time - also uses a DB as backing storage rather than XML files which should be easier to generally keep track of with regard to backing up and such forth.

On NuGet here
https://nuget.org/packages/Westwind.Globalization

Here's the project page and a summary direct from it (See the Data Driven Localization Resource Provider section).
http://www.west-wind.com/westwindwebtoolkit/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but accessing db may be a problem to me because authentication to db over proxy will take some time, another matter is that these localization read rates will be exteremely high since it will be a very busy portal and I just don't want to keep db busy with this. I can only use local resources..